# What is an efficient way if implementing hellbanning?

Tags: database, database-design, forum

I was working on a forum component for a bigger project and considered adding in a hellban feature where a mod may prevent a user's posts from being viewed by anyone but that user. This basically enforces the "don't feed the troll" rule, forcing everyone to ignore the troublemaker. Meanwhile the troublemaker likely becomes bored as he doesn't succeed in getting a rise out of anyone and hopefully moves on.

My first thought was to add in a "hellbanned" column in a post table, and create a "hellbanend" table. A hellbanned user would have their user_id added as a record to the hellbanned table, and henceforth all their future posts would have their hellbanned column set to true.

So a query showing all a topic's posts would simply show all posts where 'hellbanned = False'. And, a post operation would check if the user was in the hellban table, and if so, set the post's 'hellbanned' column to True.

I can't help but thinking there is a better way to do this; I'd really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: Interesting idea but it still seems like it would lead to a cat & mouse game since the troll can figure out what's wrong by logging out and looking at the forum. You might consider an alternative solution to implement an "ignore" feature that would allow users to hide posts from someone they object to.  I have seen this feature implemented on some forums and it works well since one man's troll is another man's entertainment. If your goal is to force a troll to "move on" start by removing offensive posts and if that doesn't work break out the ban hammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hellbanning exists at the level of the user, not individual posts, so you don't have to keep the flag at the level of the posts table at all - in fact, doing that would open you to data inconsistencies (e.g. an application bug may lead to an "incompletely" hellbanned user).

Instead, put hellbanned user ID to a separate table (and if your DBMS supports it: [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) it to avoid "unnecessary" table heap)...

```
CREATE TABLE HELLBANNED_USER (
    USER_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER (USER_ID)
)
```

...and when the time comes to exclude the hellbanned user's posts, do it similarly to this:

```
SELECT * FROM POST
WHERE USER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT USER_ID FROM HELLBANNED_USER
)
```

This should perform nicely due to the index on HELLBANNED_USER.USER_ID.

The hellbanned users are still in the regular USER table, so everything else can keep working for them without significant changes to your code.

---

Obviously, once the user is hellbanned above, *all* of its posts (even those that were made before hellbanning) would become invisible. If you don't want that, add a HELLBANNED_DATE field to the hellbanned table and then hide the posts after the hellbanning similarly to...

```
SELECT * FROM POST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM HELLBANNED_USER
    WHERE POST.USER_ID = HELLBANNED_USER.USER_ID
        AND POST_DATE >= HELLBANNED_DATE
)
```

---

Alternatively, you could just keep the HELLBANNED flag (and/or HELLBANNED_DATE) in the USER table, but you'd need to be careful to index it properly for good performance.

This might actually be a better solution than the HELLBANNED_USER, *if* you need to JOIN with the USER anyway (to display additional user information for each post), so the flag is readily reachable without doing the additional search through the HELLBANNED_USER table.

Comment: You'd want to allow the banned user to see their own posts, mind, so adding a clause in the subquery for "user_id != my_user_id" would be required.